# Webserver in node.js error in path

Tags: javascript, node.js, webserver

I'm trying to use node.js as webserver, my source is divided into four modules.

- index.js
- server.js
- router.js
- requestHandlers.js

The aim of the code is to show in /, /start and /upload different pages, while if I type another path I should get Error 404. However I get error as soon as I send the request to the server.

This is my error:

```
> Server has started. Request for /start received. About to route a
> request for /start Request handler 'start' was called.
> 
> http.js:852
>     throw new TypeError('first argument must be a string or Buffer');
>           ^ TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer
>     at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (http.js:852:11)
>     at Server.onRequest (/Users/Alessio/Desktop/Circolare/server.js:12:14)
>     at Server.emit (events.js:98:17)
>     at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2113:12)
>     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:122:23)
>     at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1971:22)
>     at TCP.onread (net.js:528:27)
```

**index.js**

```
var server = require("./server");
var router = require("./router");
var requestHandlers=require("./requestHandlers");

var handle={}
handle["/"]=requestHandlers.start;
handle["/start"]=requestHandlers.start;
handle["/upload"]=requestHandlers.upload;

server.start(router.route, handle);
```

**server.js** here is where I have the error

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

function start(route, handle) {
  function onRequest(request, response) {
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");

    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});

    var content = route(handle, pathname); //Here the ERROR
    response.write(content);
    response.end();

  }

  http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);

  console.log("Server has started.");
}

exports.start = start;
```

**router.js**

```
function route(handle, pathname){
    console.log("About to route a request for " + pathname);
    if(typeof handle[pathname] === 'function'){
        handle[pathname]();
    }
    else{
        console.log("No request handler found for " + pathname);
        return "404 Not Found";
    }
}

exports.route = route;
```

**requestHandlers.js**

```
function start(){
    console.log("Request handler 'start' was called.");
    return "Hello Start";
}

function upload(){
    console.log("Request handler 'upload' was called.");
    return "Hello Upload";
}

exports.start=start;
exports.upload=upload;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you don't `return` anything from your `route()` function on success:

```
function route(handle, pathname){
    console.log("About to route a request for " + pathname);
    if(typeof handle[pathname] === 'function'){
        return handle[pathname]();  // <-- probably need a `return` statement here...
    }
    else{
        console.log("No request handler found for " + pathname);
        return "404 Not Found";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could update the route function by adding a return to the function call handlepathname,it should work then.

```
function route(handle, pathname){
    console.log("About to route a request for " + pathname);
    if(typeof handle[pathname] === 'function'){
       return handle[pathname]();
    }
    else{
        console.log("No request handler found for " + pathname);
        return "404 Not Found";
    }
}

exports.route = route;
```

Comment: Sorry, looks like we answered at the same time. Good catch though.